# Error Android 11 -> java.net.SocketTimeoutException from Samsung physical emulator with API 30 (android 11)

Tags: java, android, sockets, java-io, java.util.concurrent

I have two physical emulators

1. Samsung phone with API 30 (android 11)
2. Samsung tablet with API 25 (android 7.1)

Whenever I am trying to run the app that connects to the socket using Samsung tablet with API 25 (android 7.1), I get the socket connected flawlessly but if I run it using Samsung phone with API 30 (android 11) I always get the following error in the stack trace :

```
java.net.SocketTimeoutException: failed to connect to /192.168.43.1 (port 5050) from /10.144.1.42 (port 50696) after 5000ms
```

Here is my code:

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
AtomicReference<String> serverIP = new AtomicReference<>("");
String localIP;
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    setWiFiAddress(getApplication());
    ExecutorService executorService = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(1);
    executorService.execute(() -> {
        Socket socket = new Socket();
        try {
            socket.connect(new InetSocketAddress(serverIP.get(), 5050), 5000);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        System.out.println("ok");
    });
}

public Boolean setWiFiAddress(Application application) {
    ConnectivityManager connectivityManager = (ConnectivityManager) application.getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);
    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.M) {
        Network nw = connectivityManager.getActiveNetwork();
        if (nw == null) return false;
        NetworkCapabilities actNw = connectivityManager.getNetworkCapabilities(nw);
        if (actNw != null && actNw.hasTransport(NetworkCapabilities.TRANSPORT_WIFI)) {
            final WifiManager manager = (WifiManager) getApplicationContext().getSystemService(Context.WIFI_SERVICE);
            InetAddress localIP = getIntAddress(manager.getDhcpInfo().ipAddress);
            if(localIP != null) {
                this.localIP = localIP.getHostAddress();
            }
            InetAddress address = getIntAddress(manager.getDhcpInfo().serverAddress);
            if (address != null) {
                serverIP.set(address.getHostAddress());
                return true;
            }
        }
    }
    serverIP.set("");
    return false;
}

private InetAddress getIntAddress(int hostAddress) {
    // Get IP Address
    byte[] addressBytes = {(byte) (0xff & hostAddress),
            (byte) (0xff & (hostAddress >> 8)),
            (byte) (0xff & (hostAddress >> 16)),
            (byte) (0xff & (hostAddress >> 24))};

    try {
        return InetAddress.getByAddress(addressBytes);
    } catch (UnknownHostException e) {
        return null;
    }
}
```

}

I was searching online so many suggestions is to add `android:usesCleartextTraffic="true"` in the `<application ....> </application>` AndroidManifest.xml but this did not fix the problem.

I also made sure that I have all the list of permissions required in my app:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.MANAGE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_WIFI_STATE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CHANGE_WIFI_STATE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_PHONE_NUMBERS" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECEIVE_BOOT_COMPLETED" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CHANGE_NETWORK_STATE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.hardware.location.gps" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.hardware.location.network" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.GET_ACCOUNTS" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WAKE_LOCK" />
<uses-permission android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.permission.RECEIVE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CAMERA" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.VIBRATE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.SEND_SMS" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_PHONE_STATE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECEIVE_SMS" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.FOREGROUND_SERVICE" />

<uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.camera" />
<uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.camera.autofocus" />

<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
```

I wonder why I get this part of the error: `from /10.144.1.42 (port 50696)` because the network subnet is: 192.168.43.x and the server socket is located at 192.168.43.1 (it is the wifi server as well).

Answer (score 0):

It seems to be security issue.
If the network  is private socket will open.